# How to Databind AutoSuggestBox ItemSource and Text to a LINQ-Function

Tags: vb.net, uwp

I'm new to UWP and I'm not very experienced in databinding either. Given both I wonder if there is a more straight forward approach to what I'm trying to do.

I have an AutoSuggestBox where both ItemSource and Text are bound using x:Bind

```
<AutoSuggestBox x:Name="AutoBox" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.FilteredNames}" Text="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.SearchedName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

My ViewModel looks roughly like this:

```
Public Class ViewModel
    Inherits BindableBase

    Private _searchedName As String
    Private _filteredNames As List(Of String)

    Public Property SearchedName As String
        Get
            Return _searchedName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            MyBase.SetProperty(Of String)(_searchedName, value, "SearchedName")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property FilteredNames As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return GlobalVariables.DetailsProvider.GetListOfNames(_searchedName)
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Where the GlobalVariables-Class is basically a Singleton giving me access to DetailsProvider which in turn contains this function:

```
Public Function GetListOfNames(Optional ByVal filterString As String = "") As List(Of String)
    Dim returnNames As New List(Of String)

    'Using LINQ to filter what is searched for
    Dim filteredNames = From item As InterestingObject In Me
                        Where item.Name.StartsWith(filterString)
                        Order By item.Value
                        Select item.Name Distinct

    For Each name In filteredNames
        returnNames.Add(name)
    Next
    Return returnNames
End Function
```

Last not least I have the EventHandler for TextChanged on my AutoSuggestBox:

```
Private Sub AutoBox_textchanged(sender As AutoSuggestBox, args As AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs) Handles AutoBox.TextChanged
    ViewModel.SearchedName = sender.Text
    'the Code in Question
    sender.ItemsSource = ViewModel.FilteredNames
End Sub
```

This works as expected.

HOWEVER:

I think constantly re-binding the ItemsSource is not what DataBinding is all about. Is there another way to trigger the re-reading of the ViewModel.FilteredNames property?

I tried making it read and write and artificially "updating" the ViewModel.FilteredNames property from within the Setter of Viewmodel.SearchedName but that leads to a loop where the GetListOfNames-function is called repeatedly resulting in a stack overflow somehow.

Any suggestions are welcome.

P.S.: I tried to simplify my code by removing the application context in the variable and property names. I hope the code is still consistent :-)

Comment: "I tried making it read and write and artificially "updating" the ViewModel.FilteredNames property from within the Setter of Viewmodel.SearchedName but that leads to a loop", provide these relative code snippet to let us see if any problems.

Comment: Thank you Sunteen Wu but I have moved away from UWP and am building the solution in WPF now. So I can't really provide the code anymore.